# Rasa chatbot default entity values if not specified

Tags: rasa-nlu

I'm creating my first chatbot using rasa, I'm wondering if it is possible to set a default entity value for a specific set of  text, eg. value:"set value to user location", text: "what's the weather like outside?", entity:"location". If it's possible how is it done?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can consider `outside` as your entity and configure response according to the default value you want to set.

Comment: thanks, that really helped a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You could also have slot with default value

```
slots:
  location:
    type: unfeaturized
    initial_value: "user_location"
```